# Does "stupidity" and "courage" affect the performance of kerbonauts?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

With the latest patch Kerbonauts can gain skill as Pilots, Engineers, and Scientists. Besides that they only have the two distinguishing traits *Stupidity* and *Courage*.

Apparently the latter two affect the reaction of Kerbonauts to situations e.g. stupid courageous ones grin in dire situations, while smart anxious ones are shown with a horrified portrait.

Do *Stupidity* and *Courage* affect gameplay? If yes, in what way?

Comment: [Extraplanetary Launchpads](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/59545) is one mod that uses the Kerbals' stupidity and courage levels, as explained [in a tutorial writeup by Starstrider42](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/59545?p=1233759&viewfull=1#post1233759). (Sorry, I would have left this as a comment but my rep is not high enough yet.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does affect the texturing of the kerbonauts but the stupidity and courage in no way affect the actual gameplay. Although, there are some mods which take stupidity and courage into account. But, I can't think of any of them right this moment.

Comment: You made me curious: which mods take stupidity and courage into account?